# How to change the container according to the index of a bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have this curved navigation bar but I don't know how to change the content of the container according to the index of the page.
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)

Comment: You can use [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html). For me, it is much more convenient, because the horizontal swipe feature is already added.

Comment: I like it too but I want to use bottom nav bar this time, Thanks AnyWay.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :
1- Make ANY NUMBER of different screens and make Them a stateless widget for example.
2- import them to your Navigation bar screen.
3- Make a Widget and call it container `Widget container;`
4- Add SetState the container widget according to the index of the page to the onTap property and setState the Container Widget to The screen You want to show.
5- call your `Widget container` to child of another `container()`.
And That's it